# Visual Studio C# debug console application that is part of web solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

If I make a stand-alone console project in its own solution, debug launches the application in a cmd window. Great. This is what I want.

If I create a console project inside an existing solution built originally to house an API/MVC application, debug launches the new console application as if it is a web application. Not so great.

Is there a way to ask Visual Studio to debug the console app as a console app, and the MVC app as an MVC app while leaving both inside the same solution?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073855/debug-console-application-inside-of-a-web-application) seems relevant, but I don't understand the answer well enough to be sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your console project as the startup application by right clicking on the project in the solution explorer and clicking "Set as StartUp Project".

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thanks!